# Simplest case of loading an image via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm not having any luck pulling an image file into an image element using jQuery.  This looks pretty simple, but I'm obviously missing something very elementary.  (I'm a complete jQuery tyro, so I've likely made a silly mistake somewhere.)

All files are in the same directory (html, jquery-1.10.2.min.js, myImage.png).

The text shows up, but no image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
    </head>

    <body>
        beforeimage
        <img id="myImageElement" src="" />
        afterimage

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#myImageElement').load('myImage.png');
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try setting the `src` property of the `img` tag instead.

```
$('#myImageElement').attr("src","myImage.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
        $('#myImageElement').attr('src', 'http://davidnaylor.org/temp/thunderbird-logo-200x200.png');
});
```